# Get numeric page id as variable in Wordpress 3.2 with Thesis Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-thesis-theme

**Ive found the answer was that Neglected to put $post in global within my function**

I need to get the page id as a variable so I can use it in a switch statement for varying purposes.

I'm using WP 3.2 + Thesis 1.8 - all brand spankingly new.

I've tried all sorts of different code that worked fine in WP 2.9 running a standard theme but no luck.

**Any code I use for this will be written in wp-content\themes\thesis_182\custom\custom_functions.php**

Comment: Where do you want the page_id?

Comment: I'll be using it everywhere - every page, in header, footer, body etc so it needs to be global. I've edited my original question to include the file path.

Comment: Doh!

Didn't put $post in global within my functions...

That was 5 hours well spent.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need page_id? You could just check

```
if ( is_page(<page_id>) ) {
.....
....
}
```